# IFrameElement will reload after keyboad opening in flutter pwa

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

there is a IFrameElement which shows a url, when ever the user click the input inside our IFrameElement the keyboard will open and after that widget suddenly will be reloaded.

```
import 'package:anymeet/core/ui/fakeUi.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'package:anymeet/core/ui/realUi.dart' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Element;
import "package:universal_html/html.dart";

class WebViewWeb extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;

  const WebViewWeb({Key key, this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WebViewWebState createState() => _WebViewWebState();
}

class _WebViewWebState extends State<WebViewWeb> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'html-view',
      (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
        ..src = widget.url
        ..style.border = "0"
        ..attributes.addAll({"webkitallowfullscreen": "true", "mozallowfullscreen": "true"})
        ..allow = "camera *;microphone *;midi *;encrypted-media *;fullscreen *;usermedia *;",
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HtmlElementView(viewType: 'html-view');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that i was using canvasKit so canvas  attached to each HtmlElementView and the canvases rerender on window resize.when i disabled canvasKit
my problem solved